# Minimap view for a d3 diagram in a layout?

Tags: d3.js, dhtmlx, svgpanzoom

I'd like to include **a helicopter view (or minimap view) in a layout with d3 diagrams**. I am using **ariutta's svg-pan-zoom**, but the thumbnail view doesn't behave as expected. After many tests, I've found no way to get it. I'd really appreciate any suggestion.

Here there is the jsfiddle with a simplified version of what I have. To make it easy, a big part of code has been removed and a d3noob tree diagram has been used. We also use **dhtmlx**, but this part has also been removed from this jsfiddle (maybe later we can consider including it) : [jsfiddle with our code](https://jsfiddle.net/5jnypjLv/8/)

This is what I want to get:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EekLl.jpg)

So as to display the diagram in the thumbnail view, the d3 chart is **encoded (base64)** and used as background image for the thumbnail view (also tried as src).

Possible causes:

- dhtmlx
- dynamic svg
- encoded (base64) svg

**Thanks in advance!**

That's a simplified version of the code (without using dhtmlx).

HTML code

```
    <div id="mainScreen" style="height:100%; width:100%; position:absolute;" >
        <!-- Original: svg instead of div -->
        <!-- <svg id="diagramLayout" style="height:100%;width:100%;position:absolute;">
                </svg> --> 
                <div id="diagramLayout" style="height:100%; width:100%; position:absolute;"></div>
                <div id="thumbViewContainer">
                      <svg id="scopeContainer" class="thumbViewClass">
                        <g>
                          <rect id="scope" fill="red" fill-opacity="0.1" stroke="red" stroke-width="2px" x="0" y="0" width="0" height="0"/>
                          <line id="line1" stroke="red" stroke-width="2px" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="0"/>
                          <line id="line2" stroke="red" stroke-width="2px" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="0"/>
                        </g>
                      </svg>
                <img id="thumbView" type="image/svg+xml" src="" class="thumbViewClass" />
      </div>
</div>
```

Main JS code (it needs thumbnailViewer.js and svg-pan-zoom.js, but not included here)

```
         //------ Tree Layout: https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/43a860bc0024792f8803bba8ca0d5ecd
 var treeData =
                  {
                    "name": "Top Level",
                    "children": [
                      { 
                        "name": "Level 2: A",
                        "children": [
                          { "name": "Son of A" },
                          { "name": "Daughter of A" }
                        ]
                      },
                      { "name": "Level 2: B" }
                    ]
                  };



                // Set the dimensions and margins of the diagram
                var margin = {top: 20, right: 90, bottom: 30, left: 90},
                    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
                    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

                // append the svg object to the body of the page
                // appends a 'group' element to 'svg'
                // moves the 'group' element to the top left margin
                var svg = d3.select("#diagramLayout").append("svg")
                    .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
                    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                  .append("g")
                    .attr("transform", "translate("
                          + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

                var i = 0,
                    duration = 750,
                    root;

                // declares a tree layout and assigns the size
                var treemap = d3.tree().size([height, width]);

                // Assigns parent, children, height, depth
                root = d3.hierarchy(treeData, function(d) { return d.children; });
                root.x0 = height / 2;
                root.y0 = 0;

                // Collapse after the second level
                root.children.forEach(collapse);

                update(root);

                // Collapse the node and all it's children
                function collapse(d) {
                  if(d.children) {
                    d._children = d.children
                    d._children.forEach(collapse)
                    d.children = null
                  }
                }

                function update(source) {

                  // Assigns the x and y position for the nodes
                  var treeData = treemap(root);

                  // Compute the new tree layout.
                  var nodes = treeData.descendants(),
                      links = treeData.descendants().slice(1);

                  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
                  nodes.forEach(function(d){ d.y = d.depth * 180});

                  // ****************** Nodes section ***************************

                  // Update the nodes...
                  var node = svg.selectAll('g.node')
                      .data(nodes, function(d) {return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

                  // Enter any new modes at the parent's previous position.
                  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append('g')
                      .attr('class', 'node')
                      .attr("transform", function(d) {
                        return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")";
                    })
                    .on('click', click);

                  // Add Circle for the nodes
                  nodeEnter.append('circle')
                      .attr('class', 'node')
                      .attr('r', 1e-6)
                      .style("fill", function(d) {
                          return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
                      });

                  // Add labels for the nodes
                  nodeEnter.append('text')
                      .attr("dy", ".35em")
                      .attr("x", function(d) {
                          return d.children || d._children ? -13 : 13;
                      })
                      .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
                          return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start";
                      })
                      .text(function(d) { return d.data.name; });

                  // UPDATE
                  var nodeUpdate = nodeEnter.merge(node);

                  // Transition to the proper position for the node
                  nodeUpdate.transition()
                    .duration(duration)
                    .attr("transform", function(d) { 
                        return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
                     });

                  // Update the node attributes and style
                  nodeUpdate.select('circle.node')
                    .attr('r', 10)
                    .style("fill", function(d) {
                        return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
                    })
                    .attr('cursor', 'pointer');


                  // Remove any exiting nodes
                  var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
                      .duration(duration)
                      .attr("transform", function(d) {
                          return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")";
                      })
                      .remove();

                  // On exit reduce the node circles size to 0
                  nodeExit.select('circle')
                    .attr('r', 1e-6);

                  // On exit reduce the opacity of text labels
                  nodeExit.select('text')
                    .style('fill-opacity', 1e-6);

                  // ****************** links section ***************************

                  // Update the links...
                  var link = svg.selectAll('path.link')
                      .data(links, function(d) { return d.id; });

                  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
                  var linkEnter = link.enter().insert('path', "g")
                      .attr("class", "link")
                      .attr('d', function(d){
                        var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0}
                        return diagonal(o, o)
                      });

                  // UPDATE
                  var linkUpdate = linkEnter.merge(link);

                  // Transition back to the parent element position
                  linkUpdate.transition()
                      .duration(duration)
                      .attr('d', function(d){ return diagonal(d, d.parent) });

                  // Remove any exiting links
                  var linkExit = link.exit().transition()
                      .duration(duration)
                      .attr('d', function(d) {
                        var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y}
                        return diagonal(o, o)
                      })
                      .remove();

                  // Store the old positions for transition.
                  nodes.forEach(function(d){
                    d.x0 = d.x;
                    d.y0 = d.y;
                  });

                  // Creates a curved (diagonal) path from parent to the child nodes
                  function diagonal(s, d) {

                    path = `M ${s.y} ${s.x}
                            C ${(s.y + d.y) / 2} ${s.x},
                              ${(s.y + d.y) / 2} ${d.x},
                              ${d.y} ${d.x}`

                    return path
                  }

                  // Toggle children on click.
                  function click(d) {
                    if (d.children) {
                        d._children = d.children;
                        d.children = null;
                      } else {
                        d.children = d._children;
                        d._children = null;
                      }
                    update(d);
                  }
                }


                // Don't use window.onLoad like this in production, because it can only listen to one function.
                function Reset() {
                    if(panZoom !== undefined){
                        panZoom.destroy();
                    }                   
                    panZoom = svgPanZoom('#diagramLayout', {
                      zoomEnabled: true,
                      dblClickZoomEnabled: false,
                      fit:true,
                      controlIconsEnabled: false
                    });
                    loadMiniMap();
                }
                function load() {
                    panZoom = svgPanZoom('#diagramLayout', {
                        zoomEnabled: true,
                        // dblClickZoomEnabled: false,
                        // fit:true,
                        // controlIconsEnabled: false
                    });

                    loadMiniMap();

                }

                function loadMiniMap() {

                    var emebd = document.getElementById("thumbView");
                    //get svg element.
                    var svg = document.getElementById("diagramLayout");


                    //get svg source.
                    var serializer = new XMLSerializer();
                    var source = serializer.serializeToString(svg);


                    var mySVG64 = window.btoa(source);

          emebd.style.backgroundImage = "url('data:image/svg+xml;base64," + mySVG64 + "')";

          emebd.style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";
          emebd.backgroundAttachment = "fixed";
          emebd.style.backgroundPosition = "center";
          emebd.style.backgroundSize = "contain"; 
          //emebd.src = "data:image/svg+xml;base64, "+ mySVG64 

                    thumbnailViewer({mainViewId: 'diagramLayout',thumbViewId: 'thumbView'});
                }
```

CSS code

```
.node circle {
      fill: #fff;
      stroke: steelblue;
      stroke-width: 3px;
    }

    .node text {
      font: 12px sans-serif;
    }

    .link {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #ccc;
      stroke-width: 2px;
    }



    #mainViewContainer {
        width: 95%;
        height: 95%;
        border: 1px solid black;
        margin: 10px;
        padding: 3px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    #mainView {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        min-height: 100%;
        display: inline;
    }

    .thumbViewClass {
        border: 1px solid black;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 12px;
        right: 15px;
        width: 12%;
        height: 15%;
        margin: 3px;
        padding: 3px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    #thumbView {
        z-index: 110;
        background: white;
    }

    #scopeContainer {
        z-index: 120;
    }
```

Comment: Working demo:http://ariutta.github.io/svg-pan-zoom/demo/thumbnailViewer.html
More details in ariutta's Github:
https://github.com/ariutta/svg-pan-zoom#demos

Comment: Just in case you find it useful, here I leave some links:



http://www.billdwhite.com/wordpress/2013/12/02/d3-force-layout-with-pan-and-zoom-minimap/

http://www.billdwhite.com/wordpress/2014/02/03/d3-pan-and-zoom-reuse-demo/

http://svgdiscovery.com/

https://codepen.io/StephanT/pen/GZzPaX/

http://jsfiddle.net/m3snq/3/

http://jsfiddle.net/m3snq/6/

http://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Sublime-Text-Style-Page-Scrollbar-With-Minimap-Infoscroller.html



https://www.magnoliyan.com/mini-map/demos/window.html

http://unclenorton.github.io/jquery.infoscroller/

Comment: That's roughly 1.3k lines of code :-O And the JSFiddle isn't even working. I doubt there will be much help, if you cannot break it down to the actual problem and provide a [mcve]—emphasis on the **M**!

Comment: Yeap, sorry. As from line 414 (js) are needed scripts (thumbnailViewer.js and svg-pan-zoom.js from ariutta's github), but not my code. I'm trying to make jsfiddle works. Its just I changed my charts for a simple one because mine need data from my server.

Comment: Hi @altocumulus, here I've simplified the jsfiddle code. Hope it'll be easier to work with now. I've removed dhtmlx too. Definitely, I'll need to integrate it in a dhtmlx layout, but let's see if going step by step it's possible to find a solution.

Comment: It should really be just a **minimal** example; this is still way too much. It might even be an interesting problem, but there is a reason why this has not received any comments nor an answer! You should really strip this down to the bare minimum demonstrating your problem, even if that it will not resemble your original code. For the demo you won't need all the CSS styling, the divs in you HTML and most parts of your JS. If I am not misled, you should be able to do this based on a static SVG with less than 20 lines of code.

Comment: Hi @altocumulus, thanks again for your interest and suggestions. Ok. I'll try to strip it down as much as I can. I understand what you mean. But I am afraid to make a demo too much different from what I have to do... Apart from some CSS rues, I don't know what else I can remove. I think I have to use a dynamic d3 diagram. ariutta's demo already works with static (:ariutta.github.io/svg-pan-zoom/demo/thumbnailViewer.htm‌​l ). Maybe (not sure) the problem is creating the minimap for a dynamic SVG (and/or using dhtmlx, which I've already removed to simplify the demo).

Comment: And the divs come also from ariutta's demo. There're 250 lines of js, but the first 200 lines are just a d3 tree diagram found on the internet (bl.ocks.org/d3noob/43a860bc0024792f8803bba8ca0d5ecd).

Comment: I'll clean jsfiddle up more. I get your point, @altocumulus. But I don't know if I can simplify it much more. Anyway, I repeat that I thank your interest and suggestions to get more answers and help.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5jnypjLv/8/